# Difference between void* and char*

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, void-pointers, pointer-address

```
char srch(char x[],char k){
int i=0;
while(x[i]!='\0')
{
    if(k==x[i])
    {
       const char *h=&(x[i]);
       const void *l = h;
       cout<<"\n\nTHE CHARACTER "<<x[i]<<" FOUND AT ADDRESS "<<l<<"\n\n\n";
       exit(0);
    }
    i++;
}
return NULL;
}

int main(){
system("cls");
char str[20],ch;
cout<<"ENTER THE STRING:-\n";
gets(str);
cout<<"ENTER THE CHARACTER WHICH YOU WANT TO SEEK:-\n";
cin>>ch;

srch(str,ch);

if(NULL);
cout<<"\n\nCHARACTER NOT FOUND ";}
```

NOW, if my string is "tarun" and my character to be seeking is 'a' then it perfectly shows the address of 'a'.
BUT
If I replace my srch function by this:-

```
    char srch(char x[],char k){
int i=0;
while(x[i]!='\0')
{
    if(k==x[i])
    {
       const char *h=&(x[i]);
       const char *l = h;
       cout<<"\n\nTHE CHARACTER "<<x[i]<<" FOUND AT ADDRESS "<<l<<"\n\n\n";
       exit(0);
    }
    i++;
}
return NULL;}
```

then instead of the address, it shows arun.
Why this happened when I used char* instead of void* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Character pointer (`char*`)** has overloaded output operator (`operator<<`), and prints underlying C-style string instead of adress of a pointer. This overload exists in order to support code like this:

```
std::cout << "some string";
```

`"some string"` type is actually `const char*`, without the overload it would print an adress of string instead of the string itself.

**Void pointer (`void*`)**, or any other pointer type (AFAIK) doesn't provide this kind of overload, so the printed value is pointer adress.

Comment: Can `char*` and `void*` be of different size ?